# How is it possible to produce picovolts or femtovolts?

Tags: voltage

How is it possible to produce picovolts or femtovolts? (artificially)

Comment: Cool down a resistor.

Comment: Sure with an Agilent Keithley 6 to 8 digit DMM. How about a  petavolt?

Comment: With a common battery you can produce several billion picovolts.